# How to to code for certain values shown on a "select" element to be locked based on what was chosen on a previous "select" element

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to code for certain values shown on a "select" element to be locked based on what was chosen on a previous "select" element. Ex. If the customer chooses the Family Plan-Main Line (highlighted in image link below) on a "select" element line 1 (ex. cellular plan for 1st device in image link below), then when choosing plans on other "select" element lines (ex. cellular plan for 2nd device in image link below) the Family Plan-Main Line is no longer able to be selected but all other plans can be, such as the Family Plan-Additional Line.
I can't seem to find a solid solution for this, but I'm not the best at js, so hopefully one of you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks :)

EDIT: Here is the cost calculator I am using: **http://documentation.bold-themes.com/cost-calculator/whats-in-the-box/**

[image: examples image]

Comment: Yes, of course it's possible. But you'll have to share some code if you want us to help you with it.

Comment: Are you using react, jquery or any sort of framework?

Comment: Did you search? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+disable+select+option

Comment: The cost calculator I am using is from Envato Market: https://codecanyon.net/item/cost-calculator-wordpress-plugin/12778927 
Looks to be using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Yes - use the `disabled` attribute:

```js
document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("change", e => {
  document.getElementById("two").querySelectorAll("option").forEach(o => {
    if ((e.target.value == "even" && parseInt(o.value) % 2 != 0) || (e.target.value == "odd" && parseInt(o.value) % 2 == 0)) {
      o.disabled = "disabled";
    } else {
      o.disabled = "";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="one">
  <option value="even">Even numbers</option>
  <option value="odd">Odd numbers</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am using this cost calculator: http://documentation.bold-themes.com/cost-calculator/whats-in-the-box/
 I appreciate your help, but honestly, I am very green at coding so what you guys posted is still a little more advanced for me. Any chance the link I gave you might help give you a better idea on how I might go about coding this right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing plain old javascript, then you can do something like that:

```js
const select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
const select2 = document.getElementById('select2');


select1.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    if(event.target.value === "1") {
        select2.querySelector('option[value="1"]').disabled = true;
        select2.querySelector('option[value="2"]').disabled = false;
        select2.querySelector('option[value="3"]').disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        select2.querySelector('option[value="1"]').disabled = false;
        select2.querySelector('option[value="2"]').disabled = true;
        select2.querySelector('option[value="3"]').disabled = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<select id="select1">
<option value="1">Disable 1 and 3</option>
<option value="2">Disable 2</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```